# for loop with multiple conditions in Bash scripting

Tags: bash, for-loop

It's been a while since I've done intense bash scripting and I forgot the syntax for doing multiple conditions in a for loop.

In C, I'd do:

```
for(var i=0,j=0; i<arrayOne.length && j<arrayTwo.length; i++,j++){
  // Do stuff
}
```

I've been googling for a while and have only found syntax involving nested for loops, not multiple conditions to one for loop.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sounds like you're talking about the *arithmetic for loop*.

```
for ((i = j = 0; i < ${#arrayOne[@]} && j < ${#arrayTwo[@]}; i++, j++)); do
    # Do stuff
done
```

Which assuming `i` and `j` are either unset or zero is approximately equivalent to:

```
while ((i++ < ${#arrayOne[@]} && j++ < ${#arrayTwo[@]})); do ...
```

and slightly more portable so long as you don't care about the values of `i`/`j` after the loop.

Answer (score 3):

There is not a big difference if you compare it with C

```
for (( c=1,d=1; c<=5 && d<=6; c++,d+=2 ))
do
        echo "$c : $d"
done
```

Comment: Well that's the C-style syntax and I haven't tried that. I was more interested in something like

for i in $things; do
  ..
done

Comment: if you have just one loop you can do it like this:
    `x[0]="test 1"; x[1]="test 2"; for i in "${x[@]}"; do echo $i; done`

Comment: `for in` iterates arguments. It doesn't have anything to do with "conditions" and can't do the equivalent of the c-style loop without nesting. `for i in "${arrayOne[@]}" "${arrayTwo[@]}"; do` would iterate the elements of each array sequentially.

Comment: That last part is the exact syntax I was looking for, but it's great to know the c style syntax. Thanks for the explanation @ormaaj. I'll mark you as the answer for that great comment.