# For loop with multiple conditions in bash

Tags: bash, for-loop, multiple-conditions

first of all, i've read the question [for loop with multiple conditions in Bash scripting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10342184/for-loop-with-multiple-conditions-in-bash-scripting) but it does not work for what i intend to do. In the following script, a first for loop assign **f** quantity of  arrays to a pair of variables (**CON_PERC and CON_NAME**)

```
f=0
for i in "${container[@]}"; do
CON_PERC[$f]=$(awk '{print int($2+0)}' <<< ="${container[$f]}") #CON_PERC[0] = 2; CON_PERC[1] = 0
CON_NAME[$f]=$(awk '{print $1}' <<< "${container[$f]}") #CON_NAME[0] = hi; CON_NAME[1] = bye
((f++))
done
```

what i need to do now, is in a separate loop, check every array of both variables and print themm. what would be the best way to do it?

what i tough is something like this

```
e=0
for ((x in "$CON_PERC[@]" && z in "$CON_NAME[@]")); do
echo "${CON_NAME[$e]}  ${CON_PERC[$e]}"
((e++))
done
```

but it seems that **for ((i in "$CON_PERC[@]" && e in "$CON_NAME[@]"))** isnt valid in bash.

The question is, what is the best way to approach this, should i exclusively use a nested loop or is other way around it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you have one way :

```
#!/bin/bash


CON_PERC=(1 2 3)
CON_NAME=("Hello" "Hallo" "Hola")

for item in "${CON_PERC[@]}" "${CON_NAME[@]}"
do
    printf "Item : $item\n"
done
```

This will print :

```
Item : 1
Item : 2
Item : 3
Item : Hello
Item : Hallo
Item : Hola
```

Hope it helps!

Edit :

If you want you want you can use a traditional for loop as well. Im assuming both arrays will have the same size :

```
#!/bin/bash


CON_PERC=(1 2 3)
CON_NAME=("Hello" "Hallo" "Hola")

for (( i=0 ; i < "${#CON_PERC[@]}"; i++ ))
do
    echo "${CON_PERC[i]} : ${CON_NAME[i]}"
done
```

Comment: hey thanks, the second way is exactly what i wanted to do

Answer (score 1):

You need to nest them like this (untested in your examples)

```
for x in "$CON_PERC[@]";
  do
  for z in "$CON_NAME[@]";
  do
    echo ${CON_NAME[$e]}  ${CON_PERC[$e]}
    ((e++))
  done
done
```

e.g.:

```
for x in {a..b};
do
  for y in {c..d};
  do
    echo $x $y
  done
done
```

result:

```
a c
a d
b c
b d
```

Comment: so there's no other way than nested to do it?

Comment: Not as far as I'm aware - no

edit: this seems like it might work:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22840498/bash-script-with-double-for-loop-over-multiple-arrays-with-access-to-array-names

where by you combine x and z as a single thing and iterate over that instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through the array keys of one of your arrays and use this key to get the value:

```
CON_PERC=( 01 02 03 04 )
CON_NAME=( one two three four )

for i in "${!CON_NAME[@]}"; do
  printf '%s %s\n' "${CON_NAME[i]}" "${CON_PERC[i]}"
done
```

Output:

```
one 01
two 02
three 03
four 04
```